# Highlight text passage in non searchable PDF

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr

I please need your input to find a general approach to find a text passage in a scanned image pdf and highlight it.

When using the OCR function from google cloud I'm just getting an array of all words in the image including position. So I could find a word and highlight it, as I can search for the word and get to position of it.

But how could I search for a text passage?

I would be happy to get some ideas from you :)

Thanks!

Comment: So in other words, you use OCR to [create a searchable PDF?](https://ocr.space/searchablepdf) If so, "normal" text search should work

Answer (score 0):

I guess that with OCR you mean **[Optical character recognition](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)**.

I can think of this far fetched solution (assuming you have the position as coordinates x and y):

-Create an ordered list with of all words. The order should go like this*: word1>word2 if x1>x2 AND y1=y2 (horizontal ordering) or if x1=x2 AND y1>y2 (line ordering).

-Find the first word of the passage, check if the next entry on the list match and so on. An easier way would be finding the first and last words an highlight every word in between those, but it can create overlaps if the words are common.

This should work as long as the text is not *very* tilted. If it is you should calculate the inclination and correct it.

*EDIT: Maybe it's easier if you first order the lines and then the words. After that join the lists.